# Symbol resolution prevented by differences in class StrTrait?

Tags: c++, mfc, exe, atl, unresolved-external

In a new application, MyProg.exe, I would like to re-use a function defined in another dll/lib, MyDll.lib/.dll. The call has this signature:

```
CString CallToDllCodeFuncFromExe( const CString & someStr );
```

In MyProg.exe I #include the dll’s header file and input the MyDll.lib so the linker can resolve it, but I get an unresolved symbol.

MSDN tells me that one reason why this occurs may be that “A function is used but the type or number of the parameters do not match the function definition”. That seems to be the case here. Below is a comparison of the unmangled signatures for the function taken from the exe error messages and from a dumpbin of MyDll.lib. Notice that there is a difference in StrTraitMFC and StrTraitMFC_DLL which keeps it from resolving:

**Build error message (unresolved symbols) of MyProg.exe:**

__cdecl CallToDllCodeFuncFromExe(class ATL::CStringT< wchar_t,class *StrTraitMFC*< wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT< wchar_t> > > const &)

**Dumpbin /exports of MyDll.lib for CallToDllCodeFuncFromExe:**

__cdecl CallToDllCodeFuncFromExe(class ATL::CStringT< wchar_t,class *StrTraitMFC_DLL*< wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT< wchar_t> > > const &))

But in practice I notice that there is a workaround. All I need to do is template the function and the call works fine. Here is IntToStr with one token template parameter by value:

```
template< int N > CString IntToStr( int N )
{
  CString intToStr;
  intToStr.Format( L"%d", N );
  return intToStr;
}
```

And the call is:

```
CString str = IntToStr< 33 >( 33 );
```

And the exported function looks like this:

class ATL::CStringT< wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL< wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT< wchar_t> > > __cdecl IntToString(int)

My questions are, why does this workaround work and why doesn’t the non-templated call not work? Is it just a Visual Studio inconsistency/bug or is there something more C++ abstract going on here?

Comment: `CString` is a typedef that resolves to different types depending on project settings. As a corollary, if you use `CString` in a DLL's public interface (which is unwise, for many reasons), it can only be consumed by clients built with the exact same settings; all modules must agree on exactly what `CString` means. In your case, the difference is in `Project > Properties > General > Use of MFC` (one has it as static library, the other as a DLL).

Comment: As to the template function - it's not imported from the DLL at all. You have provided the implementation in the header - this implementation gets inlined at the call site. The EXE doesn't in fact take a dependency on the DLL (run it without, see for yourself).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That should really be an answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: "As to the template function - it's not imported from the DLL at all. You have provided the implementation in the header "

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: "As to the template function - it's not imported from the DLL at all. You have provided the implementation in the header " But if I remove the template and just inline the implementation in the header, I get multiple definitions when I compile, so it seems that the template workaround is still the only candidate for re-using code across different library types. Templating causes code generation to occur only when usage dictates an implementation's presence. Thus, no multiple definitions.

Comment: Mark your non-template with `inline` keyword, then you won't have redefinition errors.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: "Mark your non-template with inline keyword...". Reviewing inline I now see that "Function-local static objects in all function definitions are shared across all translation units (they all refer to the same object defined in one translation unit)"(cppreference). Your comment should be elevated to Answer (how?) and makes unnecessary my discussion about template workarounds. inline is a very tidy C++ solution to re-using code across library types. Another clumsy solution recommended and used in the past is the pimpl idiom. MSDN does not address this topic adequately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reusing across library types", but note that with `inline` function, same as with your template-based approach, you are not really reusing anything. You certainly don't use any code from your DLL - you just, essentially, copy that code to your EXE. It's not clear to what extent this satisfies your requirements (which were never explicitly stated).

Comment: inline satisfies perfectly because I am able to write-the-code-once-and-use-it-in-multiple-(different/separate)-projects which in this case happens to have two different library types: MFC Static and MFC DLL. It's a code-maintenance issue. I understand that this is a different kind of re-use as in executing the same code, which doesn't apply here. I am suggesting that having the ability to copy a piece of perhaps hard-to-develop-and- hard-to-maintain-code is very valuable in certain cases like this. Otherwise, the code in question becomes a liability if and when things change in the code.